# <li> style appearing in webpage when it shouldn't

Tags: html, css, html-lists, background-color

Currently working with a website, and I'm running into a weird issue. The code at fault is this:

The style sheet behind the `<ul>`, `<b>`, and `<li>` tags looks like so:

```css
ul.secretariat {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 12pt;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="secretariat">
  <li><b>Item one</b> Faculty Advisor</li>
  <li><b>Item two</b> Secretary-General</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

I am well aware that the majority of those don't affect the text; I included them to show that the CSS isn't the culprit (I don't think so, anyway. I'm no expert on HTML, someone just asked me for a favor). The issue I'm having is that in the webpage, the first item in the list has a background color that I can't get rid of. If I inspect element, I find something even stranger; [a style has appeared in the `<li>`!](http://i.imgur.com/oJQn8DJ.png) I don't know where it's coming from. I've Ctrl+F'ed ever file in the site and can't find that text anywhere. Overwriting with `style = "background: none"` doesn't seem to do anything, (I don't know if that's valid, I can't find much documentation for creating an empty background) so I would really appreciate any help I could get on this small but annoying issue.

Comment: is there a javascript code at work here?

Comment: It must be some javascript adding this inline style. Just to make sure open Dev Tools then press `F1` and check Disable Javascript. Reload your website and most probably the style won't be there anymore. If that's the case, you will need to find the javascript file that is adding this property.

Comment: Use the `!improtant` declaration to override inline styles from an external source, eg: `background: transparent !important`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to find the code that is messing with your elements `style` attribute, you can:

1. Select the element in chrome dev tools
2. Toggle `Break on Attribute Modification`
3. Refresh the page
4. Execution will pause in the violating code

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Found the culprit within a javascript file

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is very broad it is very difficult to see where the change is taking place, however this JQuery should fix the issue, add it to the bottom of the page, right before the closing `</body>` tag, see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/c5moax9h/1/

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.secretariat > li').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'inherit');
  });
});
</script>
```